# remove duplicate from datatable and appen the value vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a datatable with two columns and duplicate records in the name column, want to remove the duplicate column but not the value of duplicate column, need to append with ","

```
Name    Value
Arun    x,c
Kumar   j,k
Jai     a,b
Balu    a,c
Kumar   j,m
Arun    c,x,w
```

i want the output as

```
Name    Value
Arun    x,c,w
Kumar   j,k,m
Jai     a,b
Balu    a,c
```

Comment: If you are never going to have duplicate values in the first column, best you can do is to define this column as primary key. Try to add features to a database by coding when the feature can actually be aim directly from the database is a big mistake.

Comment: Is your datatable data are came from database?? then the best way is to manipulate in your **SELECT STATEMENT**...use **SELECT DISTINCT**.

Comment: I am getting this record from a excel file, i am importing from to excel datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this (the idea of how this works is stated in comments) :

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
'source DataTable has 2 columns : Name and Value
dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(String))
'add 2 rows to source DataTable
dt.Rows.Add("Arun", "x,c")
dt.Rows.Add("Arun", "c,x,w")

'group rows by Name
'for each group join value by comma so "x,c" + "c,x,w" become "x,c,c,x,w"
'then split by comma and call distinct to remove duplicate chars. result: x|c|w
'join them again by comma. result: "x,c,w"
Dim query = (From row In dt
            Group row By name = row.Field(Of String)("Name") Into nameGroup = Group
            Select New With {
                .Name = name,
                .Value = String.Join(",", String.Join(",", nameGroup.Select(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Value")).ToList()).Split(",").Distinct())
                }
            ).ToList()

Dim dt2 As New DataTable
dt2.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
dt2.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(String))
'add distinct data to result DataTable
For i As Integer = 0 To query.Count
    dt2.Rows.Add(query(i).Name, query(i).Value)
Next
```

Comment: Showing error : value of type 'system.collections.generic.list(of string)' cannot be converted to 1- dimensional array.  "nameGroup.Select(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Value")).ToList()"

Comment: what .NET version you use? try to change `.ToList()` with `.ToArray()`. `String.Join` in older version of .NET can only receive array, doesn't work with List.

Comment: Using framework 3.5, still showing error after changing toList() with ToArray()   " Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>d__7a`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'. "

Comment: add `.ToArray()` after `.Distinct()`. Distinct() returns list, so you need to convert it too.

Comment: Is there any way other than using LINQ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT Name,Value + ',' + value  
FROM Table1
Group By Name,Value
```

Comment: I am getting this record from a excel file, i am importing from to excel datagridview